# Find references to loaded dlls

Tags: c#, dll, mef

I have an application that can be customized by writing custom extensions. All of them are in `proj\Extensions` folder. At runtime my `Core` project loads every extension from the folder and executes code. The problem is when one of the extensions uses additional libraries, because the `Core` project cannot find reference to these additional libraries.

So for example in my `Core` project I have:

```
public void Preview(IFileDescription fileDescription)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileDescription.FilePath);
    var reader = _readerFactory.Get(extension);
    Data = reader.GetPreview(fileDescription);
}
```

In one of my extensions I have

```
public DataTable GetPreview(IFileDescription options)
{
    var data = new DataTable();
    using (var stream = new StreamReader(options.FilePath))
    {
        var reader = new CsvReader(stream); // <- This is from external library and because of this Core throws IO exception
    }
    /*
     ...
    */
    return data;
}
```

`Core` only knows about the interface, so when one of readers uses for example `CsvHelper.dll` I get exception of `FileNotFound`, because `Core` cannot find `CsvHelper.dll`. Is there any way to tell the compiler to look for additional libraries in specific folder? I used `Reference Paths`, but it didn't solve the problem. It still threw the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can attach to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event and manually load the required DLLs from your add-in directory. Execute the following code before executing any add-in code:

```
var addinFolder = ...;

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
{
    var missing = new AssemblyName(e.Name);
    var missingPath = Path.Combine(addinFolder, missing.Name + ".dll");

    // If we find the DLL in the add-in folder, load and return it.
    if (File.Exists(missingPath))
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(missingPath);

    // nothing found, let .NET search the common folders
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I'll accept this answer in 7 minutes :)